# Jquery not reloading div after modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtree

I have this function to that loads data into my tree view. I am using JQTree to do this:

```
function loadTree() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("DisplayChildren", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $("#tree").empty();
            $("#tree").tree({
                data: result,
                closedIcon: $('<i class="fa fa-folder"></i>'),
                openedIcon: $('<i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>')
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I call it when I first load the page and also when my modal window closes like this:

```
$(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
     loadTree();
     $("#modal").empty();
});
```

The problem now is that when I add an item to the page and I empty and re-call the function, my div is just empty only.

I have tried $('#tree').tree('reload'); as well but nothing happens.

Comment: Does your result data look okay after the console.log call?

Comment: Yes, it looks good. When I add data, the array number grows by 1

Comment: That's helpful. I'm not familiar with the JQTree library but I added the tag here so hopefully we'll get a user who is. Looks to me like you should just call `$("#tree").tree("reload");` instead of `loadTree()` in the modal close event handler.

Comment: I tried that as well. Will open up an issue there to see if Im missing something. Thanks!